# ROS Microcontroller cpp support?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, c++, libroscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this momment I only know a cpp API for Arduino/AVR. Do you know other existing cases?

It is planned to support more microcontrollers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52569/ros-microcontroller-cpp-support?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial) is not tied explicitly to Arduino/AVR, but is instead a serial protocol that could be used with any embedded-scale device.

I believe that it was intended to be easily portable to embedded devices with a C++ compiler.

Something else that may be of interest to you is [rosserial_embeddedlinux](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_embeddedlinux), which uses the same rosserial protocol to communicate with embedded linux devices.  The author writes:

> This package contains
> embedded-linux-specific extensions
> required to run rosserial on a small
> embedded linux system such as the
> VEXPro controller, Chumby alarm clock,
> WRT54GL router, Raspberry Pi, or many
> similar devices.

If you are interested in contributing to the longer-term embedded device goals of the ROS community, I encourage you to check out the [ROS Embedded SIG](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-embedded).

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-01-17**:
Thanks. Pretty cool. Specially this is what I was looking for. That stack doc has changed substantialy since I last visited it.